# Standart deviation of a hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, hypergeometric-function

So, here is the problem, I have 40 green marbles and 60 red marbles. 20 marbles are taken without replacement. Determine the standard deviation of the number of green marbles taken.

I used the formula for the variance in a hypergeometric distribution:
$$n\left(\frac{K}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-K}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1}\right)$$

and got:

$$20\left(\frac{40}{100}\right)\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)\left(\frac{80}{99}\right)= 3.\bar{87} $$

I took the root of this and got $\sigma \approx 1.97$ but there is no such answer for me to mark, did I make a mistake? If yes where?

Answering options:

a)0.2329

b)8

c)10.69

d)59.878787...

e)7.74

Comment: I don´t see, that you have made a mistake. What are the answering options ?

Comment: Just edited above adding the answering options

Comment: May be the question was intended to be for the expected value, 8 ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, this must be the case.